# Gravity Forms not loading under https, jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, javascript, forms, ssl, https

I am using Gravity Forms on my Wordpress site, and so far so good. The problem is I have made the page secure (https/SSL), and this is making the form not to work.

It looks like the issue is how the site is trying to load jQuery. There are 23 JS errors on the page, which seem to be due to a failed jQuery load `"Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"`.

If I go to the page where the source is trying to pull the jQuery file, you'll see the error:`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js?ver=3.4.2`

Screenshot of the error:
[image: https jquery error]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

And this screenshot is the reference in the page source:
[image: source page]

So I have been told I'd want to look into that - that's where the ultimate issue is, but I don't really know what to do next.

Is it failing because of Gravity Forms, the HTTPS plugin from Wordpress, my SSL certificate...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure it's because the [official jQuery CDN](http://jquery.com/download/) doesn't support HTTPS - use [Microsoft's](https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js) or [Google's](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js) instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer! I have multiple things working on JS such as a slider and the forms. If I change to Google's CDN, for example, will it still be working?
I'm quite new to all this, so your help is much appreacited.

Comment: Sure - you're just loading jQuery from somewhere else. For maximum assurance, load the same version as you were before (1.7.1)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! 
I've just installed a Wordpress plugin that lets me choose the CDN. wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-jquery-cdn/installation But still not working, and if I look at the source code, it's still requesting code.jquery instead of google, so I guess it must be the Gravity Forms plugin that needs changing (and not the Wordpress theme), right?

Comment: It's probably because you're not loading jQuery correctly in the first place - you should be using `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' )`. I suggest you remove jQuery from your theme, uninstall that plugin, then check out [this tut](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/) to implement.

Comment: I did this and it's working flawlessly now! I just had to change the URL to Google's CDN in the functions.php

Thanks a lot mate!